# gdal.Warp reading 2d multichannel array incorrectly - loading bands (3) as the y axis

Tags: python, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, array

We have a python script that downloads NOAA GOES satellite NetCDFs, and processes the image datasets via Pillow\OpenCV. Then I convert it back to a GDAL dataset in order to translate and warp. With a lot of tweaking, I got it back into the proper array shape and it translates just fine, however when it gets to the warp stage, it acts as if it's getting the array in the wrong order again (or doesn't know how to handle the multiple channels).

First, gdal.Translate required me to move the axes from (1500, 2500, 3)* to (3, 1500, 2500) in order to bring the dataset in properly. No problem there.

But then when I warp the result, it gets scrambled again, and is once again trying to make the number-of-bands be the y-axis, giving me a result that is 3 pixels tall. DO I really need to move the axes again? What is going on here? This only happens with RGB (multichannel) arrays, when running a grayscale, single channel image through the process there are no issues without the extra raster bands.

Relevant code:

```
newview = np.moveaxis(im_arr_contrasted, -1, 0) # (1500, 2500, 3) to (3, 1500, 2500)

procd_dataset = gdal_array.OpenArray(newview)
procd_dataset.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)
procd_dataset.GetRasterBand(2).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_GreenBand)
procd_dataset.GetRasterBand(3).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_BlueBand)

# These values come from the source NetCDF files metadata. They get lost in the image processing steps and conversions between Pillow.image arrays and numpy arrays, so we copy them back in...
procd_dataset.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
procd_dataset.SetProjection(projection)
procd_dataset.SetSpatialRef(srs)

transoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(format = 'GTiff', outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32, creationOptions = ["PHOTOMETRIC=RGB", "BLOCKXSIZE=256", "BLOCKYSIZE=256"], outputSRS = proj4str, unscale = True)
nc_procd_t_dataset = gdal.Translate('inmem_procd_t_ds.tif', procd_dataset, options = transoptions)

# So far, so good - image dataset metadata is present, etc.

print('Projecting (Warping) Image...')
warpoptions = gdal.WarpOptions(dstSRS = 'EPSG:4326', dstNodata = 0, resampleAlg = 'cubicspline', width = w_width, height = w_height)
nc_w_dataset = gdal.Warp('/vsimem/inmem_w_ds.tif', nc_procd_t_dataset, options = warpoptions)
print('Projection (Warp) completed.')

x = 0 # origin coordinate
y = 0 # origin coordinate
for b in range(nc_w_dataset.RasterCount):
    band = nc_w_dataset.GetRasterBand(b+1)
    print("band" + str(b+1))
    array = band.ReadAsArray(x,y,1,1)
    print(array)
    
if render_rgb == True: w_procd_temp_image = Image.fromarray(numpy_w_img_dataset, 'RGB')
w_procd_image = w_procd_temp_image.convert('RGBA')

print('Image Layer mode: ' + w_procd_image.mode + '. Size: ' + str(w_procd_image.size))

# Output:
# Projecting (Warping) Image...
# Projection (Warp) completed.
# band1
# [[0.]]
# band2
# [[0.]]
# band3
# [[0.]]
# Image Layer mode: RGBA. Size: (2300, 3)
```

- In **GDAL** terms: (y-pixels, x-pixels, number-of-channels)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** The array shape that worked with gdal.Translate was (y-pixels, x-pixels, number-of-channels), which is rather odd (I corrected my footnote above), in typical raster datasets it is ordered x-pixels, y-pixels, number-of-channels.

Perhaps I need to perform a similar re-ordering of the array axes priot to warping, but it sure seems like there should be an easier way to go from gdal.Translate to gdal.Warp without changing the data structure!

Comment: BTW, to avoid confusion, the warped dimensions are different. The resulting array SHOULD look like (5000, 2300, 3)

Also note that is the correct order I believe (x-pixels, y-pixels, number-of-channels). I know I sent it to the translate with the x,y reversed - maybe that's part of the problem? It came out of that process looking correct however...

Comment: Do you know that the axis order of EPSG:4326 is latitude-longitude? See https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html#crs-and-axis-order. Maybe that has some effect. Have you ever considered to use the gdalwarp library version for warping https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py?

Comment: Well that would explain the order being different. I wonder if Translate got the update and Warp did not? I'll do some more experimenting and post results... including trying that utility and a subprocess call to the command line version.

Comment: Translate does not change the coordinate system so it does not change the axis order either. Warp is changing the axis order if needed, for example when reprojecting from UTM (easting-northing) into EPSG:4326 (lat-lon). But the axis order thing is complicated, and NetCDF is at least as complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, etc. @user30184, I think you're definitely on the right track. The metadata is coming out with 'Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2' and it should be reversed (based on working examples*), and I think it's related to GDAL switching to being more EPSG compliant as you mentioned above. 

* The sample GeoTIFFs are from NESDIS (https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/), and they have an extra metadata element:
"Warning 1: The definition of geographic CRS EPSG:4326 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry." 
Now I think I understand why..!